# How to Search through a list of Integers in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Okay so I'm extremely new to Haskell, and i know there's a lot of info on this stuff but i just don't understand it. If someone could help explain and show me what I'm doing wrong that would be greatly appreciated,

here's some of the code:

```
n = 8                     -- number of ingredients (excluding cream)

type Recipe = [Integer]   -- some ingredients

-- list all recipes with k of n ingredients

choose :: Integer -> Integer -> [Recipe]
choose n k
  | k == 0    = [[]]      -- only recipe with no ingredients

  | n == k    = [[1..n]]  -- only recipe with all ingredients

  | otherwise = choose (n-1) k ++ map (++ [n])(reverse (choose (n-1) (k-1)))

-- omlette legality (rules must hold conjunctively)

legal r = head $ map (\rule -> False) ruleset

ruleset = [rule0, rule1, rule2, rule3, rule4, rule5, rule6, rule7]


-- Rule 0: If truffles, then precisely truffles.
rule0 r = False

-- Rule 1: Either truffles, garlic, cream, or precisely one meat.
rule1 r = False 


-- Rule 2: Not both peppers and onions.
rule2 r = False
```

and Here are the ingredients

```
bacon     = elem 1
peppers   = elem 2
ham       = elem 3
mushrooms = elem 4
sausage   = elem 5
onions    = elem 6
garlic    = elem 7
truffles  = elem 8
cream     = elem 9
```

Now I'm trying to change the Rules to make them meet the commented out requirements, essentially searching through the list of ingredients,
I've tried something along the lines of

```
r = if any ( 5== ) Recipe
```

but obviously it's not working, could someone elaborate on what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Your question is a bit scattered and hard to follow.  Can you provide a minimal example of what exactly you're wanting to do with the expected output and any compiler errors you've encountered?  Also, you might be looking for something along the lines of `any (== 5) [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, which would compile, but `if any ( 5== ) Recipe` isn't correct syntax since `if` must have `then` and `else`, and `Recipe` is a type, not a value.

Comment: It seems like "rules" should be predicates on recipes (ie, of type `Recipe -> Bool`). For example, you can write rule 2 (this recipe does not have both peppers and onions) as `\r -> not (pepper \`elem\` r && onion \`elem\` r)`. Is this what you are looking for? It is unclear what 'legal' should do; the comment refers to the conjunction of rules but your code does nothing of the sort.

Comment: Sorry, let me fix my question, i was given code by my teacher, and it's supposed to be broken code. It compiles and runs but does not operate as it should. There are many commented "rules" now, these rules are supposed to essentially return a bool, example: " if truffles, then precisely truffles", im trying to search through each list of recipe and see if it abides by the rule.. if that makes any sense..

Answer (score 2):

Don't work with numbers but use your own data type, e.g.

```
data Ingredient = Bacon 
                | Peppers 
                | Ham 
                | Mushrooms 
                | Sausage
                | Onions 
                | Garlic
                | Truffles 
                | Cream 
                deriving (Eq, Ord, Bounded, Enum)
```

You get a range of ingredients by using functions like `enumFromTo`

Then you can write things like

```
rule2 receipt = not ((Peppers `elem` receipt) && (Onions `elem` receipt))
```

And you can test if all rules apply using

```
legal receipt = all ($ receipt)  ruleset
```